# Java Tree Error

Tags: java

I am trying to implement an array based tree where each node has a list of child nodes and I am getting an error that I need help fixing.

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lassign2Trees.ArrayTreeNode;
 at assign2Trees.ArrayTree.<init>(ArrayTree.java:15)
 at assign2Trees.ArrayTree.main(ArrayTree.java:97
```

)

The error comes from here I believe:

```
ArrayTreeNode<E>[] tree = (ArrayTreeNode<E>[]) new Object[1];
```

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lassign2Trees.ArrayTreeNode;
 at assign2Trees.ArrayTree.<init>(ArrayTree.java:15)
```

refers to this line:

```
 ArrayTreeNode<E>[] tree = (ArrayTreeNode<E>[]) new Object[1];
```

You cannot cast an `Object[]` to any other type.

Even if this worked, you have another error immediately after this: arrays in Java are indexed starting at 0, not 1. To access the first element in an array, you would refer to `tree[0]`.

Comment: @Brian, you cannot instantiate a generic array (i.e. `ArrayTreeNode<E>[size]`). For storing the nodes in your array, you could just drop the type parameter (the `<E>` part) and use the raw type - `ArrayTreeNode[] tree = new ArrayTreeNode[size]`. In addition to this, I think you may want to re-think your overall strategy here - you seem to have a mixture of storing elements in an array (but the array is only of size 1, and you never resize it) and storing the nodes in a tree with references to parents and children. Assuming this is HW, I don't think this is what you are being asked to do.

Comment: Wikipedia has a decent description of the common way to store a binary tree in an array: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Ahnentafel_list